# Input form not working - updating bootstrap-vue version

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using a form and I have a numeric field in one of the inputs, however when opening the modal of the form when editing a line, the error below is displayed:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected String with value "1", got Number with value 1.

My code:

```
    <b-col md="6" sm="12">
        <b-form-group label="Code:" label-for="institution-code" label-size="sm" class="mt-0 mb-0">
            <b-form-input id="institution-code"
                label-for="institution-code"
                size="sm"
                type="number"
                v-model="institution.code" required
                placeholder="Insert code..." />
        </b-form-group>
    </b-col>
</template>

export default {
data: function() {
    return {
        institution: {},
```

**Old Version: "bootstrap-vue": "2.0.0-rc.11",**

**New Version: "bootstrap-vue": "2.0.0-rc.12",**

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You should not use `v-model.number` on `b-input` as Vue does not support `v-model` modifiers on custom components. Instead use the `number` prop.

Comment: @Hiws I already tried to use the prop number, but my v-model is an object and I was unable to use the prop as an object.

Can you please tell me how to do it, because I have read the documentation but I still don't understand it.

Comment: `<b-form-input>` only accepts either a `string` or `number`. It doesn't support an Object.

Comment: In the version "bootstrap-vue": "2.0.0-rc.11", it was perfectly acceptable, it was only the update that started showing these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed update to version to working:

**New Version: "bootstrap-vue": "2.0.0-rc.13",**

```
    <b-col md="6" sm="12">
        <b-form-group label="Code:" label-for="institution-code" label-size="sm" class="mt-0 mb-0">
            <b-form-input id="institution-code"
                label-for="institution-code"
                size="sm"
                type="number"
                v-model.number="institution.code" required
                placeholder="Insert code..." />
        </b-form-group>
    </b-col>
</template>

export default {
data: function() {
    return {
        institution: {},
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the v-model.number to v-model="your property"

Comment: Where do I modify this? in the input I already defined type = "number"

Comment: Why did you use v-model.number?

Comment: Hope you know v-model serves you as data-binding in ur inputes, which helps to update the input value automatically. So since institution is an object and also the property to hold the input value you should do it this way. **v-model="institution.prop"** **prop** should be ur object property.

Comment: Your input type number, already handled that for you.

Comment: <b-col md="6" sm="12">
        <b-form-group label="Code:" label-for="institution-code" label-size="sm" class="mt-0 mb-0">
            <b-form-input id="institution-code"
                label-for="institution-code"
                size="sm"
                type="number"
                v-model="institution.code" required
                placeholder="Insert code..." />
        </b-form-group>
    </b-col>
</template>

export default {
data: function() {
    return {
        institution: {},

Comment: Where's the change? It is very difficult to detect if the code stays in the comment.

Comment: Sorry about that, just remove the .number from ur v-model and make sure the property you are storing the input value exist in ur Vue data property

Comment: What I don't understand, is how to add the institution object as a "props"

Comment: I thought props are mainly used for components

Comment: You need to add a props property to the component, then bind the values to the input. E.g props: [''value']

Comment: Then go to the template and add **v-bind:value="value"**

Comment: But how do you do that taking into account what institutions is an object?

Comment: Your props can also be an object, just bind the property value to ur template read more here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: I've read the documentation before, but I couldn't understand ... can you exemplify what you said in the answer with the same example I gave in the question?

Comment: My phone will be dead soon, more words will be cheap, code examples would be preferable, but can do that with my phone now. Chat me on FB with http://facebook.com/fritz.darlington

Comment: Okay, I called you there.

Comment: You can help-me?